# Check if location layer was changed. Yandex MapKit 3.0

Tags: android, geolocation, mapkit, yandex, yandex-maps

How to check if i change camera location for disable anchor?
I dont see solution in [examples](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo) or [docs](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/about-docpage/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
public class WorkFragment extends BaseFragment implements ..., CameraListener {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(){
   ...
   mapView.getMap().addCameraListener(this);
    ....
}

@Override
public void onCameraPositionChanged(Map map, CameraPosition cameraPosition, CameraUpdateSource cameraUpdateSource, boolean b) {
  if (cameraUpdateSource == CameraUpdateSource.GESTURES) {
    ...
  }
}
```